# Date type returning 1970-01-01 as default always in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, date

`setDOB` method is always inserting 1970-01-01 in database.

Can't change the `dataType` of DOB which is Date in java.util.
**JSON postman request is recieving like this:**

```json
{
"DOB":"20101123"
}
```

Request will be recieved in this format only, and it should insert in database like `2010-11-23`

But only 1970-01-01 is inserting in database on every request.

**ServiceClass method**

```
private void updateExistingEmployee(OrgEmployeeMap existingOrgEmployee, RequestMessage requestMessage) {
    try {
        EmployeeInformation employeeInfo = requestMessage.getEmployeeInformation();
        final var updater = new Updater(existingOrgEmployee, employeeInfo);

        updater
            .update("DOB", EmployeeInformation::getDOB, OrgEmployeeMap::getDob, OrgEmployeeMap::setDob)
            .update("Email", EmployeeInformation::getEmail, OrgEmployeeMap::getEmail, OrgEmployeeMap::setEmail);

    
        orgEmployeeMapRepository.save(existingOrgEmployee);

        log.info("Updated Employee : " + existingOrgEmployee);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        log.error("error in processing the request error", e.getMessage());
    } 
}


public static class Updater {
  private final OrgEmployeeMap existing;
  private final EmployeeInformation information;
  private final Set<String> updatedFields = new HashSet<>();

  public Updater(OrgEmployeeMap existing, EmployeeInformation information) {
    this.existing = existing;
    this.information = information;
  }

  public <T> Updater update(String fieldName,
                            Function<EmployeeInformation, T> newValueGetter,
                            Function<OrgEmployeeMap, T> oldValueGetter,
                            BiConsumer<OrgEmployeeMap, T> oldValueSetter) {
    final var newValue = newValueGetter.apply(information);
    final var oldValue = oldValueGetter.apply(existing);
    if (newValue == null || newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
      return this;
    }
    this.updatedFields.add(fieldName);
    oldValueSetter.accept(existing, newValue);
    return this;
  }

  public Set<String> getUpdatedFields() {
    return updatedFields;
  }
}
```

**DTO Class**

```
@Data
public class EmployeeInformation {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Email")
    private String Email;

    @JsonProperty(value = "EmployeeFirstName")
    private String EmployeeFirstName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "EmployeeLastName")
    private String EmployeeLastName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "DOB")
    private Date DOB;

..
}
```

**Model Class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeMap {
@Id
    @Column(name = "Id", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String Id;

    @Column(name = "firstName", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "dob", nullable = false)
    private Date dob;
}
```

Comment: FYI: Both of the terribly flawed `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. JDBC 4.2+ supports the *java.time* classes. For a date-only value, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes ``` java.time.LocalDate```  worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```java
@JsonProperty(value = "DOB")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private Date DOB;
```

Comment: yes it worked : ) Thankyou so much I was so stressed because of this

Comment: Also I'm logging fields which got updated during Api call and DOB is always logging, no matter if it has different value or not, it is always logging, Any idea why?

Comment: One comment suggests switching over to `java.time.LocalDate`. When thinking about this, I wondered if it's something to do timezones. Probably best to debug that one.

Comment: Yes ``` java.time.LocalDate``` worked. Thanks